# Supervisord: Don't restart subrocesses on failure

Tags: supervisord

How to make [supervsiord](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) process always stop when one of it's managed subrocesses stops/crashes?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
autorestart=false
```

to the relevant *subprocess*:

```
[program:x] Section
```